# resize2fs bad magic number in super-block -- Extending a Logical Volume

Tags: linux, centos

I'm following these instructions to extend the logical volume on my VM
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006371

Everything is going fine until I try extend

```
[root]# lvextend -L+1020M /dev/vg_centos6base/lv_swap
Extending logical volume lv_swap to 21.87 GiB
Logical volume lv_swap successfully resized
```

(I extended it more than this, just an example)

but then I get

```
[root]# resize2fs /dev/vg_centos6base/lv_swap
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open 
/dev/vg_centos6base/lv_swap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that you are attempting to resize a swap volume with a tool made for resizing ext* filesystem. That won't work. At least from the volume name I presume that you want to resize the swap size.

You need to turn off swap, re-create the swap space and enable it again. In shell speak:

```
swapoff /dev/vg_centos6base/lv_swap
mkswap /dev/vg_centos6base/lv_swap
swapon /dev/vg_centos6base/lv_swap
```

Linux also can use regular files as swap space. For example,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/somewhere bs=1M count=1024
```

would create a 1 GB empty file for you.

Then you initialise the file as a swap file:

```
mkswap /path/to/somewhere
```

Secure it:

```
chown root:root /path/to/somewhere && chmod 600 /path/to/somewhere
```

And enable it:

```
swapon /path/to/somewhere
```

Then you add the following line to `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/path/to/somewhere swap swap defaults 0 0
```